# How to initiate global variable in Squeak

Tags: smalltalk, squeak

I don't mean a class variable. I want a variable that can be used everywhere. How should I initiate it?

I know one way is `Smalltalk at: #variableName put: theValue.` but I don't want to give it value as soon as I create it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should do the trick:

> Smalltalk at: #VariableName put: nil

When you create a global variable in the Smalltalk dictionary, you are creating an Association which has a `key` and a `value`, so you can't get away without providing some sort of value.

You can come back later and change the value with:

> Smalltalk at: #VariableName put: newValue

Any compiled code that references the  global variable will see the new value, because the compiled code references the Association.